# django aggregate or annotate

Tags: django, aggregate, annotate

This is a very stupid thing, I know, but I just don't seem to get the handle on Django aggregate and annotate functions.

I have a very simple set of models: `Events`, `Areas` and `Types`. An event has foreign keys pointing to `Area` and `Type`. I would simply like to have the number of forthcoming events for any area and the same for any type, i.e. *Area1 - 5 forthcoming events*, *Area2 - 6*, or *Type1 - 34 events* and so on.

I would like to avoid writing custom SQL, and the q operator if possible.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) and actually tried to implement some of the examples?

Comment: Please show your code, so we can help you with a concrete problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

for a given area:

```
my_area = Area.objects.all()[0]
Event.objects.filter(area=my_area).count()
```

annotation

```
events = Event.objects.annotate(Count('area'))
for event in events:
    print event, event.area__count
```

or

```
events = Event.objects.annotate(count=Count('area'))
for event in events:
    print event, event.count
```

See the following docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Answer (score 21):

If you just need the total number of events for a single area, you don't need either `annotate` or `aggregate`, a simple `count` will do:

```
Event.objects.filter(area=my_area).count()
```

If you want the count of events for multiple areas, you need `annotate` in conjunction with `values`:

```
Event.objects.values('area').annotate(Count('area'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all very much. The problem I was having is documented in the last version, it is about the annotate and filter precedence.

```
areas = Area.objects.filter(event__in = eventQuery).annotate(num=Count('event'))
```

My error was in the fact that I was doing annotate first and filter second.

Comment: For those looking for this in the docs... [Order of annotate and filter clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

### Given the models Event and Area as:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class Area(models.Model):
    area_name = models.CharField(...)
    address = models.CharField(...)


class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(...)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area,...)
```

#### In order to get the total number of events in each area, you can do:

```
area_query = Area.objects.filter(yourfilter)
total_event_per_area = Event.objects.filter(area__in=area_query).values('area').annotate(Count('id'))
print(total_event_per_area)
<QuerySet [{'area': 2, 'id__count': 2}, {'area': 4, 'id__count': 3}]>
```